# Simulate multiple key-press combinations

Tags: java, awtrobot

I looking for a solution where I can "press" two keys at the same time using `Java` or `.NET`. Recently I have tried below code in Java which is working perfectly fine on one key. Here is the code for one key

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
```

Upon execution of this code it press letter 'R'. Now what I'm looking is to press "Windows+R" keys or say a combination of multiple keys not more than two keys at the same time.

Comment: @user3498003 what is `r` object? show some more code

Comment: @DimaGoltsman It is almost certainly the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, although I agree it would have been nice for that to be explained in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int%29) of `Robot` class, just do:

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);  // VK_WINDOWS key still pressed
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
```

the `keyPress` method does not relese the key, so this should work

Comment: +1 Works for me, in Windows 7. Although looking at other questions on this subject, it's possible results may vary according to platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got one more small question, how to increment value like VK_1 to VK_2 through program.

Comment: i think its just ints. try to print them both and look at the value